# spider scraped items from a web page but there is nothing in output

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape product name and its price from this [web page](https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men) I have written following spider

```
import scrapy
from ..items import MenDataItem
class MenCollectionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'men_collection'
    allowed_domains = ['www.exportleftovers.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men']

    def parse(self, response):

        items = MenDataItem()

        for product in response.xpath("//div[@class = 'product-list collection-matrix clearfix equal-columns--clear equal-columns--outside-trim']/div/div/a/div"):

            title =  product.xpath(".//a[@class='product-info__caption ']/div[@class='product-details']/span[@class = 'title']/text()").get()
            price = product.xpath(".//a[@class='product-info__caption ']/div[@class='product-details']/span[@class = 'price ']/span[@class='current_price']/span[@class='money']/text()").get()

            items['title'] = title
            items['price'] = price

            yield items
```

and following is `items.py`

```
import scrapy


class MenDataItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    title = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
```

and it provides following output

```
2020-04-01 19:25:07 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-04-01 19:25:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.exportleftovers.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men> (referer: None)
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men>
{'title': None, 'price': None}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (24 items) in: data.csv
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 531,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 184287,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 2, 2, 25, 9, 457430),
 'item_scraped_count': 24,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 26,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 2, 2, 25, 7, 590785)}
2020-04-01 19:25:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

As it can be seen here every time it's providing "none" value for both variables, the xpath values work fine to search 24 items on this page, as I stored output in a data.csv file, it can be seen in logs that 24 items were stored in csv file and there is nothing in output file except header names. Can anyone help

Comment: I believe is because you have to define your dictionary keys inside ```items.py``` as ```Item.Field()``` objects. Then you will need to import your item function into your spider, and finally parse the dictionary as an input of your item function. ```yield YourItemFunction(**yourDictionary)```

Comment: Tried, same output

Comment: Can you post your ```items.py``` and update your spider please?

Comment: Also, you will need to check if your ITEMS pipeline is ```on``` inside your  ```settings.py```

Comment: I have updated spider in question please have a look and even after removing comments from `ITEM_PIPELINES` in `settings.py` file nothing has changed

Comment: yes, everything seems correct! Something is weird here

Comment: Could you try printing title and price on every iteration, before the yield?

Comment: added `print(items['title'])` and `print(items['price'])` after `items['price'] = price` it just prints two more `none` in two different lies after each crawl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210820/discussion-between-enriquebet-and-raza-ul-haq).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that other approach according to what you have will be to do this:

```py
import scrapy
from ..items import MenDataItem
class MenCollectionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'men_collection'
    allowed_domains = ['www.exportleftovers.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.exportleftovers.com/collections/men']

    def parse(self, response):

        items = MenDataItem()

        titles = response.xpath("*//a[@class='product-info__caption ']/div[@class='product-details']/span[@class = 'title']/text()").getall()
        prices = response.xpath("*//a[@class='product-info__caption ']/div[@class='product-details']/span[@class = 'price ']/span[@class='current_price']/span[@class='money']/text()").getall()

        for i in range(len(titles)):
            items['title'] = titles[i]
            items['price'] = prices[i]

            yield items
```

I wonder if that will solve the problem. Let me know if it does! :D

Comment: I am sorry for replying too late. this code generates `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` error. I tried too look out for answers and everyone was saying the same but first answer to this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/88e33b/web_scraping_typeerror_nonetype_object_is_not/) which is specifically about web scraping, explains what's going on here is that "you will have this error if what you're looking for is not there". Does it make any sense?

Comment: It does, but I checked over the website that you sent and tried this XPaths, and both of them returned the correct result. Probably, when you connect to the website with scrapy you are receiving a different response.